Cadence SDF Annotator for a back-annotated simulation
I am trying to use the Cadence SDF Annotator for a gate-level back-annotated simulation.  I am working with a simple 8-bit adder in order to familiarize myself with the design flow.
I am using the following instruction in my Verilog testbench:
$sdf_annotate("gate_netlist.sdf", , , "simu.log");

However, when elaborating my simulation, I run into a problem with hierarchical paths I believe:
xmelab: *W,SDFINF: Instance add_15 not found at scope level <top-level> <gate_netlist.sdf, line 279>.
xmelab: *W,SDFINF: Instance my_add not found at scope level tb_my_add <gate_netlist.sdf, line 305>.
xmelab: *W,SDFCTE: Module tb_my_add of instance tb_my_add does not match SDF celltype of my_add, skipping annotation <gate_netlist.sdf, line 331>.

I am working with this reference I found online (sadly, it is VERY old).

These warnings indicate that some gates in the SDF file do not match up with the Verilog source code for your gate-level netlist.
One common reason is that the Verilog gate-level files were modified after you generated the SDF file.  Check the timestamps on the files, or the synthesis log files or the file histories if your files are under version control (like Git).
Another common reason is that you need to match hierarchy level between the SDF and the Verilog code.  The $sdf_annotate system task has an optional argument to pass in the hierarchy:
$sdf_annotate("gate_netlist.sdf", module_instance, , "simu.log");

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2023, section 32.9 Loading timing data from an SDF file:

module_instance—is an optional argument specifying the scope to which
to annotate the information in the SDF file. The SDF annotator uses
the hierarchy level of the specified instance for running the
annotation. Array indices are permitted. If the module_instance is not
specified, the SDF annotator uses the module containing the call to
the $sdf_annotate system task as the module_instance for annotation.

The Cadence xmhelp command can also give you more information about the simulator warnings.  For example:
xmhelp xmelab SDFCTE
xmhelp: 24.03-s002: (c) Copyright 1995-2024 Cadence Design Systems, Inc.
xmelab/SDFCTE =
    The celltype specified in the SDF file for this instance does
    not match the actual celltype of the instance in the design
    hierarchy.  No annotation will be performed to this instance.
    (Default severity: 'W')


about the option to pass the hierarchy: I added the path to my top (labelled uut) and now SDF statistics shows that 4.32% of paths are annotated (8/185 paths). Why is this percentage so low ?

@ArkhamEngineer:  Did this answer eliminate the warning messages?

not entirely :( I still have "Instance not found warnings" the problem is that on my bigger project I have a LOT of warnings, so treating them one by one is not really practical, special considering people that might take up the project in the future.
